# Trying to produce a 3D surface plot in r using the persp() function, get an error message

Tags: r, dataframe, plot

I am trying to plot a function which is dependent on two variables, x and y in a 3D surface plot in r. I get an error message which says that increasing 'x' and 'y' values expected. I am not sure how to arrange the two variables in increasing order which can help produce the plot.

my code:

```
x <- c(-1, 2, 15, 0, 1, 4, 7, 4, 5, 2)
y <- c(1.5, 3, 7, 2, 1.5, 15, 12, 8, 20, 21)
f <- sqrt(x^2+y^2)

df <- data.frame(x, y, f)

func <- function(x, y){
  df$f + (x-x + y-y)}

z <- outer(x, y, func)

persp(x, y, z,
      main="Perspective Plot of a function",
      zlab = "Height",
      theta = 30, phi = 15,
      col = "springgreen", shade = 0.5,
      ltheta = 120,
      ticktype = "detailed")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to plot a function of two variables as a surface plot, then you really don't need your two input vectors. You need a regularly spaced grid of input values in both the x and y direction that will cover the range of both inputs:

```r
f <- function(x, y) sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
x <- y <- -1:20

persp(x, y, z = outer(x, y, f),
      main="Perspective Plot of a function",
      zlab = "Height",
      theta = -45, phi = 15,
      col = "springgreen", shade = 0.5,
      ltheta = 120,
      ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]